# event.point.pageY of highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart in my app. This is part of the chart_options:

```
plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointWidth: 20
            },
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                events: {
                    click: function (event) {
                        //debugger;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Please check the line on which the debuggers is. Previously I hade there: event.point.pageY and I got the exact position of closest point of the click event.

After I updated my Highcharts version, event.point.pageY is undefined. How do I get this value?

Comment: you can try that click event in point by  point : {
      events : {
       click : function () {}}}

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi I tried and that event too has event.point.pageX as undefined.

Comment: not pageX intead point.x

Comment: Well for me pageX is printed in the event object, see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wxzry8bz/1/

Comment: @SebastianBochan event.point.pageY is undefined

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi point.x has a different value.

Comment: Let me know in which version of Highcharts event.point.pageX was proper?